# How to concatenate a character to a string?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, char, concatenation

I am trying to write a program that creates random words, using the randomgenerator. But how do i add the characters that the random generator makes, to the string? And is the "a : z" right? or how do tell the generator to use all numbers between a and z

```
public class StringTraining extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run() {
    String s1 = null;
    randomChar();
    s1.concat(randomChar());
    println(s1);
}

private String randomChar() {
    String word = rgen.nextBoolean() ? "a" : "z";
    return word;
}
```

Comment: encoding all the 26 letters with a random boolean generator is more difficult to implement compared to use of random double generator (assuming that characters are to be distributed uniformly). And no, "a".."z" implementation is not correct, right now you get either "a" or "z".

Answer (score 0):

Java `String`s are immutable, so you can't modify a string in any way. `s1.concat(...)` returns you a new `String` object. You can do something like `s1=s1.concat(...)` if needed or use the `StringBuffer` class that implements mutable strings, if you need some performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
(condition) ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

That's what your method is doing. You're saying "If we generate a true statement we use a, if we generate a false we use z."

It sounds like you want to use random characters in the RANGE of a to z. The cleanest way to do that would probably be to use characters and generating a number from a range.

Characters internally act pretty much the same as integers, where you can add to them to increment through the possible characters. Due to this, you just want to generate a character in the range 'a' to 'z'. It's been a while since I've touched java so I don't know if there's a simple way to do that. But if you want to do it in a slightly more messy way with looking up libraries that do it for you, you could just start with 'a' and generate a random number between 0 and 25 (inclusive) and add the result to 'a'. 'a' + 1 is going to return 'b', for example.

Then just append that character to your word and you'll be set!

note: characters and strings are different. This logic will NOT apply to strings. You'll need to use single quotes instead of double quotes to initialize your 'a' as a character.

Answer (score 0):

I literally spent today doing this for fun as a learning experience. Maybe someone else can give a more elegant answer than I can but here is how i did it.

```
public static String getString(){

    char[] result = new char[10];

    for(int a=0; a<result.length; a++){
        result[a] = getLetter(); 
    }

    return new String(result);
}

public static char getLetter(){

    boolean case = true;
    if((1 + (Math.random() * 2) == 2){
        case = false;
    }        

    if(case){
        switch((int) (1 + (Math.random() * 26))){

            case 1:
                return 'a';
            case 2:
                return 'b';
            case 3:
                return 'c';
            case 4:
                return 'd';
            case 5:
                return 'e';
            case 6:
                return 'f';
            case 7:
                return 'g';
            case 8:
                return 'h';
            case 9:
                return 'i';
            case 10:
                return 'j';
            case 11:
                return 'k';
            case 12:
                return 'l';
            case 13:
                return 'm';
            case 14:
                return 'n';
            case 15:
                return 'o';
            case 16:
                return 'p';
            case 17:
                return 'q';
            case 18:
                return 'r';
            case 19:
                return 's';
            case 20:
                return 't';
            case 21:
                return 'u';
            case 22:
                return 'v';
            case 23:
                return 'w';
            case 24:
                return 'x';
            case 25:
                return 'y';
            case 26:
                return 'z';

        }
    }else{
        switch((int)(1 + (Math.random() * 26))){

            case 1:
                return 'A';
            case 2:
                return 'B';
            case 3:
                return 'C';
            case 4:
                return 'D';
            case 5:
                return 'E';
            case 6:
                return 'F';
            case 7:
                return 'G';
            case 8:
                return 'H';
            case 9:
                return 'I';
            case 10:
                return 'J';
            case 11:
                return 'K';
            case 12:
                return 'L';
            case 13:
                return 'M';
            case 14:
                return 'N';
            case 15:
                return 'O';
            case 16:
                return 'P';
            case 17:
                return 'Q';
            case 18:
                return 'R';
            case 19:
                return 'S';
            case 20:
                return 'T';
            case 21:
                return 'U';
            case 22:
                return 'V';
            case 23:
                return 'W';
            case 24:
                return 'X';
            case 25:
                return 'Y';
            case 26:
                return 'Z';
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

Comment: The answer I just provided is a little bit more elegant. You were definitely on the right track! What's nice about characters is that you can increment them by adding integers, since internally a character is just a glorified int. So something like 'a' + 1 would return 'b'. 

So you just convert your int range to be 0 through 25 instead of 1 through 26, and add your result to the character 'a'. 

And there still might be something even MORE elegant using java libraries, but if your goal is self-teaching then implementing it yourself is great =)